# jquery height animate() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I just created this: [jsfiddle.net/MWzDe/](http://jsfiddle.net/MWzDe),

the JS:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  if ($('ul').height = 0) {
    $('ul').animate({'height':'100%'},'slow');
  } else {
    $('ul').animate({'height': 0},'slow');
  }});
```

I need to slide the 'ul' tag Up/Down without 'really' disappearing it. What's wrong with the code? doesn't make it yet. thanks.

Comment: Might want to check your if condition before anything else.

Comment: you might want to use `==` for comparison, not `=` (assignment). This isn't VB land where everything beaks by magic

Comment: Why not just use `slideToggle`?: `$('ul').slideToggle('slow');` ;)

Comment: slideToggle party up in here..

Comment: @musefan thanks I try using ==, but it doesn't change animate() behavior

Comment: @stefan slideToggle will make it like display:none, I need it to behave like overflow:hidden

Answer (score 6):

`.height` is a function: use `$('ul').height()` to get the height like this

```
if ($('ul').height() == 0) {
}
```

Comment: You should also use is equal to (==) instead of set equal to (=) like udidu did

Comment: sorry, the code just editted, it's my mistake, but still doesn't change anything yet

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this just using `slideToggle`.

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $("ul").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWzDe/3/

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('button').click(function () {

    $('ul').animate({
        'height':'toggle'
    }, 'slow');

});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MWzDe/9/)

Answer (score 2):

as you are using jquery, why not using `.slideToggle()` ?

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: well, actually I try to create responsive nav menu, just say I use slideToggle(), how can I dissappearing it by default? if I using css display:none; it will diseappearing it too when user resize the window up.

Comment: what do you mean, exactly? responsive is normally associated with fluid/breakpoint widths, while you are sliding up and down (vertically) a menu. If you want it invisible at page load, `display:none;` will do - that won't affect the display when the user resizes the window or scrolls up. Unless I didn't undestand what you mean?

Comment: The code above is for small screen, In case that I use slideToggle(): while the 'ul' is sliding Up/disappear it will inline styling the 'ul' with dislay:none, I've checked it with fireBug. If user resizes the window up in that state, the 'ul' still "display:none". I need it to be displaying while user resizes the window up in that 'state'. Perhaps I need it to behave like overflow:hidden; Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use slideToggle()

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/MWzDe/2/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use **.slideToggle** function. 
[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/letiagoalves/S3DQt/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code uses animate

```
$('button').on(click, function() {
    $('ul').animate({height: 'toggle'},'slow');
})
```